# Display HTML code to plain text

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I need help with including HTML code as plain text on my page. Could you tell me the best way how to place the code on my page between `<section>` & `</section>` tags?

Something like this:

[image: Example]

Thanks in advance!

So I want to place the HTML code like the w3schools posted this HTML Example on their page with the all tags and tags are colored.

Comment: just put it inside a <pre></pre>

Answer (score 1):

```
$(selector).text( ... )
```

The use of the text() function sets the value as a TextNode, which will cause the html not to render on the page.

Comment: I think he just means displaying the tags in a html textbox (not the inner text of HTML)

Answer (score 0):

< code>< /code> Perhaps with this tag you can do it

```
<code><h1>Mi header</h1></code>
```

Comment: Which tag would that be?

Comment: sorry the html did not render the tags in the answer lol

Comment: I know but I didn't know if you noticed it..

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<pre></pre>`

For example:

```
This is me code
```